# In React, how can I save an array to disk?

Tags: arrays, node.js, reactjs, save

Dumb question, I know but...
I have a file containing a simple array of simple objects. To read it, I do an import (import teams from './league.js';). Easy. But now I need to save the array whenever it's updated and can't figure out how.
I've tried using Node's 'fs.writeFile' with laughable results (an error message saying fs is not a function).
Any thoughts?

Comment: "an error message saying fs is not a function" probably because of a missing require

Comment: Nah. I've tried using both require and import. Neither makes a difference.

Comment: can you post the code that's causing the error?

Comment: handleInsertedRow(row) {
        let teams = [...this.state.teams];
        teams.push(row);
        this.setState({teams}, ()=>{
            console.log(this.state.teams);
            fs.writeFile('league.js', this.state.teams, (err)=>{
                if (err){
                    console.log('There\'s been a balls up');
                }else{
                    console.log('New data written to file');
                }
            })
        });
    }

Answer (score 1):

Node.js is for developing **server-side applications**, React applications run in the **client** (the browser), that's why you got the error.

As I understand what you are looking for is **data persistence**, this means having a database in the server that can store the data of your application. Then you can perform requests to the server in order to retrieve the data and render this data to the client in your React application.

There are many databases you can use, the most common solution for Node.js is **MongoDB** with an **express** server. But if you don't want to setup an entire Node.js application and implement you own API, I suggest you to go with **Firebase** for easily testing your application.

On the other hand, there is [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) where you can save the state of the UI so you don't have to load all the data from the server every time the application reloads (much like cookies), but I believe this is not what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi Jose,
I do not want to use a database nor use local storage. All I want to do is take a piece of data and stick it on my hard drive.